# Is the curl of a vector field only defined on $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

> Is the curl of a vector field only defined on $\Bbb R^3$?

I was wondering if the criterion $$\nabla \times \vec{F}=\vec{0} \implies \vec{F} \space\text{is conservative}$$

only applies to three dimensional vector fields or if it also applies to $n$-dimensional vector fields?

Comment: There is a condition in $n$ dimensions for conservativity of a vector field.  However, it involves ${} \gt n$ equations of expressions involving the derivatives of the components.  So it is not of the form of a vector equation in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Strictly, zero curl is not enough of a restriction to guarantee a conservative field in 3-space. You also need that [the domain is simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields).

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks! I keep forgetting that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29)

"Unlike the gradient and divergence, curl does not generalize as simply to other dimensions; some generalizations are possible, but only in three dimensions is the geometrically defined curl of a vector field again a vector field. This is a similar phenomenon as in the 3 dimensional cross product, and the connection is reflected in the notation ∇ × for the curl."

So you can define $\triangledown \times \vec{F} $ in higher dimensions but it does not have special geometrical properties there.

Comment: Is this only for higher dimensions or also for lower dimensions, i..e 2d ? thanks.